# Some delegates are not called in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, dependency-injection, delegates, viewmodel

I have a ViewModel that has a dependency that has a delegate. I need that delegate to connect with my ViewModel. I have 5 delegates, but only 3 of them work. I tried to recode it but nothing happened.

I have a basic protocol like this.

```
protocol PrayerRepositoryDelegate: class {
    func dataChanged(arr: [Prayer])
}
```

This protocol is inside my dependencies. When I change something in my array I call that function

```
var filteredPrayerArray: [Prayer] = [] {
    didSet {
        delegate?.dataChanged(arr: filteredPrayerArray)
    }
}
```

But I didn't get any response in my ViewModel for the first controller but get that response in other ViewModels. So I assume that delegate in dependencies work.

I connect delegates in `init` like this

```
init(dependency: Dependencies) {
    self.dependencies = dependency
    super.init()
    setupDelegations()
}

private func setupDelegations() {
    self.dependencies.prayer.delegate = self
    self.dependencies.popesQuotes.delegate = self
    self.dependencies.photoQuotes.delegate = self
    self.dependencies.divesInMisericordia.delegate = self
    self.dependencies.arcibishop.delegate = self
}
```

3 of them work fine, but another 2 looks like that are not connected. I connect it all as you can see. No works delegates mean that function of the delegate is not called.

Did anybody have the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I solved it! I just put `setupDelegations` into main thread like this:

```
private func setupDelegations() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.dependencies.prayer.delegate = self
        self.dependencies.popesQuotes.delegate = self
        self.dependencies.photoQuotes.delegate = self
        self.dependencies.divesInMisericordia.delegate = self
        self.dependencies.arcibishop.delegate = self
   }     
}
```